# XSLT 1.0 - Running a template on the result of another template

Tags: xml, templates, parameter-passing, xslt-1.0, java-6

I wonder how it is done by XSLT 1.0 a transformation that passes the result of one template as an input for another within a single .xslt file:

Raw XML Input > call-template(1) > re-formatted XML > call-template(2) on the re-formatted XML

***Case:***

I want to write a template to re-arrange an xml so that the attributes become elements; and then run another template on the resulting xml of the first one to remove the duplicates. I can have two xsl files and pass the result of the first transformation to the second. However, I want to do it in one xslt.

The raw  input xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <properties>
            <property name="name" value="Foo"/>
            <property name="service" value="Bar"/>
            <property name="version" value="1"/>
        </properties>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <properties>
            <property name="name" value="Foo"/>
            <property name="service" value="Bar"/>
            <property name="version" value="2"/>
        </properties>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <properties>
            <property name="name" value="AnotherFoo"/>
            <property name="service" value="AnotherBar"/>
            <property name="version" value="1"/>
        </properties>a
    </resource>
</resources>
```

When I apply the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template name="attributes-to-elements" match="/resources">
        <xsl:call-template name="get-resources" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="get-resources">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <products>
            <xsl:for-each select="resource">
                <xsl:call-template name="convert-attributes-to-elements" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </products>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="convert-attributes-to-elements">
        <product>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='name']/@value" />
            </name>
            <service>
                <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='service']/@value" />
            </service>
        </product>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am able to re-format the xml without the versions and get the output which does not contain versions and the attributes has become elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <service>Bar</service>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <service>Bar</service>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>AnotherFoo</name>
        <service>AnotherBar</service>
    </product>
</products>
```

Now, the thing I want is to pass this modified xml to some template as the **input xml** and remove the duplicates. Finally, I want to get an xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <service>Bar</service>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>AnotherFoo</name>
        <service>AnotherBar</service>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: Is your question about how to apply a template to the result of another template (and the given scenario is only an example), or are you asking how to achieve the task in the example? If the latter, it can be done in a single pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a mode to separate processing steps, and of course in XSLT 1.0 you also need an extension function like `exsl:node-set` or `msxsl:node-set` to be able to further process a result tree fragment created in another template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="group" match="product" use="concat(name, '|', service)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="step2">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="step2"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(name, '|', service))[1]))]" mode="step2"/>

    <xsl:template name="attributes-to-elements" match="/resources">
        <xsl:variable name="step1-rtf">
          <xsl:call-template name="get-resources" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($step1-rtf)/*" mode="step2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="get-resources">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <products>
            <xsl:for-each select="resource">
                <xsl:call-template name="convert-attributes-to-elements" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </products>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="convert-attributes-to-elements">
        <product>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='name']/@value" />
            </name>
            <service>
                <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='service']/@value" />
            </service>
        </product>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will need to check whether your XSLT processor supports `exsl:node-set`, MSXML needs `msxsl:node-set` instead.

Comment: Indeed, that MSXML thing is there because I created the XSLT file in Visual Studio and left the header as it is. I am going to do this transfrmation via javax.xml.transform.Transformer class in Java 1.6

Comment: Try the `exsl:node-set`, perhaps it works. If not, try `xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"` and `xalan:node-set` instead. But the Transformer can be any implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This can all be done in a single pass, if you want:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k" 
         match="resource" 
         use="concat(properties/property[@name='name']/@value, '|', properties/property[@name='service']/@value)"
/>

<xsl:template match="/resources">
    <products>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="resource[count(. | key('k', concat(properties/property[@name='name']/@value, '|',      properties/property[@name='service']/@value))[1]) = 1]"/>
    </products>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="resource">
    <product>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='name']/@value" />
        </name>
        <service>
            <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='service']/@value" />
        </service>
    </product>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```